# Flutter archive: unzip password-protected folder

Tags: flutter, dart, io

In my flutter application I have to download a password-protected `zip` folder from a remote server and import the `.sqlite` that is inside in my app.

I'm trying with [`archive`](https://pub.dev/packages/archive) library, but of course I'm open for a better solution if any.

I used the `password` parameter of `ZipDecoder().decodeBytes()` method, but it is not working for me.

```
//inside the `onDone()` callback of an http request
Archive archive = ZipDecoder().decodeBytes(
    _myDownloadedData,
    password: "mySuperSecretPsw", //here I set the archive psw
);
Uint8List fileDbBytes = Uint8List.fromList(archive.first.content);
setAsWorkingDb(fileDbBytes);
```

The `archive.first.content` from the snippet above looks still encrypted. I get the following errors:

```
E/SQLiteLog(12256): (26) file is encrypted or is not a database
E/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler(12256): Corruption reported by sqlite on database: /data/user/0/my.own.package/app_flutter/working_data.db
E/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler(12256): deleting the database file: /data/user/0/my.own.package/app_flutter/working_data.db
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
Archive archive = ZipDecoder().decodeBytes(
   _myDownloadedData,
   verify: true,
   password: "mySuperSecretPsw", )
```

Comment: `verify` param as far as i know only checks the checksum of the file for integrity